# What will post-process differentially correct raw Bad-Elf Surveyor U-Blox NMEA/raw UBX?

Tags: gps, nmea, rinex

I have a Bad-Elf Surveyor unit which claims accuracy ~1m when post-processed, but I am at a loss to find software that can differentially correct the raw NMEA/UBX logs that the unit will record.  I checked the bad-elf site to see if they had a list of apps that could do it, but couldn't find anything.

Anyone know what will take the .UBX file and correct it?

Comment: I don't know if you've tried this already, but the company website says that they have updated the iOS app to output a RINEX format, which you could then use with NRCAN's PPP service. Let me know if you try it and how it works - I have one that I'm planning on trying out in the next few months.

Comment: I have noticed their new RTK abilities in the firmware upgrades lately, but don't have an RTK account.  I'll give the RINEX export method a try, thanks!

Comment: You are looking for kinematic processing I guess. Right? For static processing DGPS there are plenty of online services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can convert them to rinex format you can use the online Precise Point Positioning (PPP) service provided by the Canadian Geodetic Survey. You can find out more at http://www.nrcan.gc.ca/earth-sciences/geomatics/geodetic-reference-systems/tools-applications/10925#ppp, or google NRCAN and PPP

It's a great service, but I'm not sure if it is intended only for Canadian data. I'm sure there are other PPP services out there as well.

Comment: Handily, I am in Canada!  However i am looking for something that will do it with a fairly simple workflow instead of having to convert file formats.  Bad Elf says the data can be post-processed but are leaving that to 3rd party app developers to tackle, but as yet i have not seen any 3rd party apps take it on, which is why I brought it up here.

Comment: Converting it to RINEX and processing online is the simplest (not autamated) workflow I think. Doing the DGPS yourself requires more software and downloading the precise ephemeris and clock files.
Also note that PPP is not DGPS.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have used the raw data logger to output a RINEX file, you can use the [RTKLib](http://www.rtklib.com/) to post-process your data using either

- a) DGPS, using RINEX data from a known base station (CACS in Canada or CORS in the
  US) or
- b) [PPP](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112718/how-is-precise-point-positioning-ppp-exactly-done), using satellite clock and ephemeris data (.sp3 and .clk files
  available from [NASA CDDIS](https://cddis.nasa.gov/Data_and_Derived_Products/GNSS/broadcast_ephemeris_data.html) and [IGS](https://igscb.jpl.nasa.gov/components/prods_cb.html)).

Bad Elf has an explanation of how to correct your data with DGPS on their website [here](https://bad-elf.com/pages/post-processing-gnss-data-with-rtklib-introduction). Also see tutorials from Latitude51 ([1](http://blog.latitude51.ca/rtklib-part-1-getting-started/), [2](http://blog.latitude51.ca/rtklib-part-2-rtk-processing/), and [3](http://blog.latitude51.ca/rtklib-part-3-precise-point-positioning-with-igs-products/); note, however, Latitude 51 is
   using L1/L2 data) and [Rtkexplorer](https://rtklibexplorer.wordpress.com/2016/02/13/kinematic-solution-with-rtkpost/). You can also find a more detailed discussion of L1-only PPP at this [GPSWorld article.](http://gpsworld.com/innovation-guidance-for-road-and-track/)

However, I've been a little frustrated with the available explanation of how the ublox chips work and how to best implement the bad-elf's capabilities, so I've opened another question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237687/how-to-achieve-optimal-accuracy-with-rinex-post-processing-for-bad-elf-or-ublox); possibly someone has some additional insights that they would like to share.